# Swt Gantt into Griffon app

Tags: griffon

we are trying to embed a Swt Gantt into our Griffon application, but for any reason that we dont know, the application does not work. We suppose that probably is something relative about threads but we are not sure.

This is the Swt Gantt: http://hexapixel.com/software/ganttwidget

Attach the source code of our test
https://github.com/ivanarrizabalaga/gantt

Regards

Answer (score 0):

attached the source code of our test

```html
    // MODEL

    class GanttModel {
     
     def view
     def controller
     
       GanttSWTBridge ganttBridge
       
       void mvcGroupInit(Map args) {
        ganttBridge=new GanttSWTBridge()
       }
    }

    // VIEW

    application(title: 'gantt',
      preferredSize: [800,600],
      pack: true,
      //location: [50,50],
      locationByPlatform: true,
      iconImage:   imageIcon('/griffon-icon-48x48.png').image,
      iconImages: [imageIcon('/griffon-icon-48x48.png').image,
                   imageIcon('/griffon-icon-32x32.png').image,
                   imageIcon('/griffon-icon-16x16.png').image]) {
        borderLayout()
        panel(id:"campaignGanttPanel", cssClass:"campaignGanttPanel") {      
          migLayout(layoutConstraints: "fill")
          //button(text:"Load Gantt",actionPerformed:controller.clickAction,constraints:"wrap")
          widget(id:'ganttBridge',new GanttSWTBridge(model.controller))
          model.ganttBridge=ganttBridge
        }
    }


    // CONTROLLER

    class GanttController {
     // these will be injected by Griffon
     def model
     def view
     
     void mvcGroupInit(Map args) {
      log.debug "Init app"
      GanttSWTBridge ganttSWTBridge=((GanttSWTBridge)model.ganttBridge)
      ganttSWTBridge.connect()
      ganttSWTBridge.init()
     }

     def clickAction={evt=null->
      log.debug "Load Gantt"
      GanttSWTBridge ganttSWTBridge=((GanttSWTBridge)model.ganttBridge)
      doLater{
       ganttSWTBridge.connect()
       ganttSWTBridge.init()
      }  
     }

     void mvcGroupDestroy(){
      model.ganttBridge.disconnect()
     }
    }

    // GANTTSWTBRIDGE

    package gantt

    import java.awt.Canvas

    import org.apache.log4j.Logger
    import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.ganttchart.GanttChart
    import org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.ganttchart.GanttEvent
    import org.eclipse.swt.SWT
    import org.eclipse.swt.awt.SWT_AWT
    import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display
    import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell

    class GanttSWTBridge extends Canvas {
     
     private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.class)
     
     Thread swtThread
     GanttChart ganttChart
     
     def controller
     
     GanttSWTBridge(def controller){
      System.setProperty("sun.awt.xembedserver", "true");
      this.controller=controller
     }
     
     public void connect() {  
      if (this.swtThread == null) {
        final Canvas canvas = this;
        this.swtThread = new Thread() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
         try {
          log.debug "Creating display and  shell"
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = SWT_AWT.new_Shell(display, canvas);
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
      
        synchronized (this) {
          log.debug "Adding gantt into shell"
          ganttChart = new GanttChart(shell, SWT.NONE);
          this.notifyAll();
        }
      
         log.debug "Opening shell"
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
          log.debug "SWT Loop"
          if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
         display.sleep();
          }
        }
        shell.dispose();
        display.dispose();
         } catch (Exception e) {
          log.debug "Exception: $e"
        interrupt();
         }
       }
        };
        this.swtThread.start();
      }
      
      // Wait for the Browser instance to become ready
      synchronized (this.swtThread) {
        while (this.ganttChart == null) {
       try {
         this.swtThread.wait(100);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
         log.debug "InterruptedException: $e"
         this.ganttChart = null;
         this.swtThread = null;
         break;
       }
        }
      }
       }
     
     /**
      * Stops the swt background thread.
      */
     public void disconnect() {
       if (swtThread != null) {
      ganttChart = null;
      swtThread.interrupt();
      swtThread = null;
       }
     }
     
     /**
      * Ensures that the SWT background thread
      * is stopped if this canvas is removed from
      * it's parent component (e.g. because the
      * frame has been disposed).
      */
     @Override
     public void removeNotify() {
       super.removeNotify();
       disconnect();
     }
     
     void init(){   
       this.ganttChart.getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
         
        log.debug "Adding data to gantt"  
        // make a 10 day long event
        Calendar cStartDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar cEndDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        cEndDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 10);
         
        // make some revised dates
        Calendar rStartDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar rEndDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        // pretend dates were 2 days earlier than the start date and 5 days later than the end date
        rStartDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -2);
        rEndDate.add(Calendar.DATE, 15);

        GanttEvent revisedEvent = new GanttEvent(ganttChart, "Revised", cStartDate, cEndDate, rStartDate, rEndDate, 50);
         }
       });
      
     }
     
    }
```